# Local and production configuration files in Maven Project

Tags: maven

I'm starting out with maven and I have a question regarding selecting resources for the deployment. I have a local and production properties directory, and I when I deploy I want to have one of them to be selected and put in the appropriate place. My project structure is something like this

```
-
| -/src
|  | -/main
|  |  | -/java
|  |  | -/resources
|  |  | -/webapp
|  |  |  | -/WEB-INF
| -/config
|  | -/local
|  |  | -/properties
|  |  |  | -config.properties
|  | -/prod
|  |  | -/properties
|  |  |  | -config.properties
| -/WEB-INF
```

So when I deploy it should select the appropriate properties folder and put it into `/WEB-INF/`. How can I achieve that?

On a side note, but also related, should the `config` directory be inside `src/main/resources`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a thing like the following (which you have already):

```
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   |-- java
    |   |-- resources
    |   |-- environment
    |   |   |-- test
    |   |   |   `-- database.properties
    |   |   |-- qa
    |   |   |   `-- database.properties
    |   |   `-- production
    |   |       `-- database.properties
    |   `-- webapp
```

Apart from the above you need for every environment a maven-assembly-descriptor like the following:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

  <id>test</id>
  <formats>
    <format>war</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/environment/test/</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

You need to change the folders according your locations and finally you need the execution of the maven-assembly-plugin to produce the appropriate artifacts like this:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>test</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/test.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>qa</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/qa.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>production</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/production.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The result will be having an artifact like

1. xyz-1.0-SNAPSHOT-test.war
2. xyz-1.0-SNAPSHOT-qa.war
3. xyz-1.0-SNAPSHOT-production.war

which will be created with a single call of maven `mvn clean package`. That's it. But you should be aware of that this approach is going into the deployment direction which is not really the job of Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest keeping it simpler. As @khmarbaise suggested, try not to mix the maven and deployment.

Work with the default war plugin structure and configuration, and have your *.properties files processed at deployment time (like having them keep tokens and replace them with the relevant values to the environment)

Splitting as you did, will require you to maintain same changes in different files. This is a slippery path to get lost in big projects.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I wrote already about the intention of Maven: `But you should be aware of that this approach is going into the deployment direction which is not really the job of Maven`.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to process my *.properties files at deployment time. I like your suggestion of using tokens and replacing them with the relevant values. Could you please elaborate on that, or point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: How is your deployment done? By the maven process? Or at a later stage?

Comment: @EldadAK I run `mvn clean install` and copy the war to my tomcat

Comment: You can use the maven [antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and use the replace task to edit the properties file. After that, use the war task to update the war with the relevant file and proceed to copy. The editing of the properties can depend on an environment variable like DEV, QA or PROD.